# How do I override a Bootstrap control with a JQueryUI one?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion, bootstrap-accordion

I need a functionality that the JQueryUI accordion control has but it's a legacy project built on Bootstrap and Bootstrap keeps taking over.

How do I select the JQueryUI version of the accordion control over the Bootstrap one?

Comment: What specific functionality do you need? I'd suggest adding it in manually to Bootstrap instead of including an entire library for it

Comment: I need to set the active tab.  In JQueryUI it's just set active to tab needed in the constructor; in Bootstrap it's arcane sorcery.

Comment: It depends on how customised the widget is. If it's not html and out-of-the-box just swap out `.collapse` for a `.accordion`. Lots of custom CSS may be quite difficult. Could you make a [mcve]?